# Unboundid sdk search through ContentSyncRequestControl not showing modified entries

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have to search modified (add, delete, modify) entries using `ContentSyncRequestControl` in Unboundid sdk, but it showing all the entries instate of modified entries.

what I have done so far

```
LDAPConnection ldapConnection = null;
    try {
        /*Apache LDAP*/
        ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection("192.168.0.0", 389);
        ldapConnection.bind("uid=test,ou=system", "mypassword");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ASN1OctetString cookie = null;
        int choice = 3;
        while (true) {
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(ldapConnection
                    .getRootDSE().getAttributeValue("namingContexts"),
                    SearchScope.SUB, "(&(objectclass=person))",
                    "createTimestamp","modifyTimestamp","sn","mobile","givenName","ucMiddleName","mail",
                    "isDeleted");
            ContentSyncRequestControl control = new ContentSyncRequestControl(ContentSyncRequestMode.REFRESH_AND_PERSIST);
                    //added control to request
            searchRequest.addControl(control);
            final SearchResult searchResult = ldapConnection.search(searchRequest);
            java.util.List<SearchResultEntry> entries = searchResult
                    .getSearchEntries();
            int count = 0;
            for (SearchResultEntry entry : entries) {
                System.out.println(entry.getAttributes());
                ++count;
            }
            System.out.println("Press 0 for exit");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            if (choice == 0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    } catch (LDAPSearchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LDAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but this shows me all entries instate of modified entries.

also when I go through `ContentSyncRequestControl` class **[API documentation](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/controls/ContentSyncRequestControl.html)** then I found following things to keep in mind.
but I dont know how I can set this following things

> 1] The associated search request should have a SearchResultListener so
>   that entries will be made available as soon as they are returned
>   rather than having to wait for the search to complete and/or consuming
>   a large amount of memory by storing the entries in a list that is only
>   made available when the search completes.
>
> 2] Entries and references returned from the search should include the
>   ContentSyncStateControl with the associated entryUUID and potentially
>   a cookie with an updated sync session state. You should call
>   getControl(ContentSyncStateControl.SYNC_STATE_OID) on the search
>   result entries and references in order to retrieve the control with
>   the sync state information.
>
> 3] If the search does complete, then the SearchResult may include a
>   ContentSyncDoneControl with updated sync state information. You should
>   call getResponseControl(ContentSyncDoneControl.SYNC_DONE_OID) to
>   retrieve the control with the sync state information.

can any one help me on this ? Thanks...

***EDIT***

after adding the control I am still getting the all entries instate of modified entries.

right now I am using

```
ContentSyncRequestControl(ContentSyncRequestMode mode)
```

constructor so how can I use this form Of constructor can some one help me

```
ContentSyncRequestControl(boolean isCritical, ContentSyncRequestMode mode, ASN1OctetString cookie, boolean reloadHint)
```

when I am using `ContentSyncRequestMode.REFRESH_ONLY` it gives me all entries but when I use `ContentSyncRequestMode.REFRESH_AND_PERSIST` mode the it ***goes in infinite loop***.

so can some one help me on this...?

Answer (score 1):

Hello i have the "same" problem

I just started with some democode, retrieve the cookie, provided it in the next run...
still get the same data returned by the search, but the entry was NOT changed ;-(
We are using OpenLdap Version 2.4.35 on RHEL6.

here some code (actually c# not java - but who cares).

```
public void LdapConnect()
        {
            //connect
            LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection("SERVER", 389, "cn=USER,dc=ksz,dc=ch", "PASSWORD");

            //search
            //ContentSyncRequestControl syncReqCtrl = new ContentSyncRequestControl((ContentSyncRequestMode.REFRESH_ONLY);

            //TEST TEST TEST
            com.unboundid.asn1.ASN1OctetString cookieOld = new com.unboundid.asn1.ASN1OctetString("rid=111,csn=20140409143056.252248Z#000000#000#000000");
            ContentSyncRequestControl syncReqCtrl = new ContentSyncRequestControl(ContentSyncRequestMode.REFRESH_ONLY, cookieOld, false);             
            //reloadHint - Indicates whether the client wishes to retrieve an initial content during an incremental update if the server determines that the client cannot reach convergence with the server data.

            SearchRequest searchReq = new SearchRequest("dc=ksz,dc=ch", SearchScope.SUB, "(uid=student)", "*");//new string[]{"mail", "username"});
            searchReq.addControl(syncReqCtrl);

            SearchResult searchRes = connection.search(searchReq);

            String mail = null;
            if (searchRes.getEntryCount() > 0)
            {
                SearchResultEntry entry = (SearchResultEntry)searchRes.getSearchEntries().get(0);
                mail = entry.getAttributeValue("mail");

                //eat cookie here or later???
                ContentSyncStateControl syncStateCtrl = (ContentSyncStateControl)entry.getControl(ContentSyncStateControl.SYNC_STATE_OID);
                com.unboundid.asn1.ASN1OctetString leckerSearchCookie = syncReqCtrl.getCookie();
            }

            //syncrepl        
            //TODO in future use:
            //-AsyncSearchResultListener

            //request state, provide cookie if you have one. REFRESH_ONLY:just to this point, no psuh notification
            ContentSyncDoneControl syncReqDoneCtrl = (ContentSyncDoneControl)searchRes.getResponseControl(ContentSyncDoneControl.SYNC_DONE_OID);
            if (syncReqDoneCtrl != null)
            {
                //have a cookie
                com.unboundid.asn1.ASN1OctetString leckerEndCookie = syncReqDoneCtrl.getCookie();
            }


            //syncReqState.getMode().name
            //state
            //ContentSyncState syncState = null;
            //ContentSyncStateControl syncStateCtrl = new ContentSyncStateControl(syncState,);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're actually adding the control to the search request.  You should use searchRequest.addControl(control) before calling ldapConnection.search.

Comment: I made changes but still not able to get modified entries please check my updates...

Comment: can you add some code so that I can get more understanding of how to search modified entries using this ContentSyncRequestControl